# Can we add additional Jmeter Load generators during the test execution?

Tags: jmeter

We are running test from distributed master slave machines. We need to add additional load generators during the execution of test whenever the memory consumption of the slaves increase from a certain threshold. 
Main Question: Can we add more ips(slave machines/load generators) in the jmeter cmd during execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not add additional slaves machine once test started. Alternatively, you can start separate new test.